# Showing a recurrent event is transient

Tags: probability

> In a sequence of independent throws of a perfect die let $\mathcal{E}$ stand for the event that the accumulated numbers of ones, twos, ..., sixes are equal. Show that $\mathcal{E}$ is transient recurrent event and estimate the probability $f$ that $\mathcal{E}$ will ever occur.

There are a total of $6^t$ possible sequences of die roll of length $t$. There are $\binom{t}{t/6}$ ways to place the ones. Then there are $\binom{5t/6}{t/6}$ ways to place the twos, continuing in this fashion we get the probability is $\frac{\prod_{i=1}^6\binom{it/6}{t/6}}{6^t}$. To show that this is transient we show that $\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\prod_{i=1}^6\binom{im}{m}}{6^{6m}}<\infty$. I was thinking that we can upper bound $\prod_{i=1}^6\binom{im}{m}$ by some $r^m$ an use geometric series formula, but I'm not sure if that's doable. Some hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is a "transient recurrent" event? I don't know how to interpret that; I've only encountered those words to be mutually exclusive of one another.

Comment: if $f_n$ is the probability that an event $\mathcal{E}$ occurs for the first time at round $n$ then a transient recurrent event satisfies $\sum_n f_n<1$. This is given in chapter 13 of William Feller's book on probability. There is a theorem that says if $u_n$ is the probability that an event occurs at round $n$ then for a transient event it's necessary and sufficient that $\sum_n u_n < \infty$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that almost surely the accumulated numbers of ones, twos, ..., sixes are equal only finitely many times, you can use Borel Cantelli Lemma.

Call $A_n$ the event « in the $6n$ first rolls, we get exactly $n$ ones, $n$ twos, ..., $n$ sixes. Then $P(A_n) = (6n)!/n!^6 \times (1/6)^n$ (the product of binomial coefficients that you found can be simplified).

Then Stirling formula shows that $P(A_n) \sim cn^{-5/2}$ as $n \to +\infty$ for some positive constant $c$, so the series $\sum_n P(A_n)$ converges.